# Is there a way to check JPA methods with a single entity return that they are using only columns with unique constraint?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

For example, I have a method as such `public User findOneByLastName(String lastName)` but I do not have a unique constraint on the column "lastName" so this can fail at runtime with an exception `NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2` if there are more than one users in the database with the same last name.

Question: Is there a way to force JPA to fail to compile if he finds that the query is trying to get one result using a parameter which is not marked with `@Column(unique = true)`?

Comment: Not so minor observation : JPA does not compile anything... So to be clear, you are asking for a way to fail the java compilation with an error for cases like this ? Or you are looking for a tool (e.g. static analysis like Sonar, or IDE based checks) that could report it ? Or you are looking for a runtime exception ? I do not know of any such tools, but I guess it's important to frame the need / problem as accurately as possible. A sidenote : there might be a `unique=true` constraint in the java code, but there might not be a unique constraint in the physical DB - and there's no tool for that.

Comment: Correct, I used a wrong word there, I was thinking of an exception that is thrown during application startup like `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException` is thrown when you use a property name that does not exist. Something like that would be ideal, but any tool that would warn about that would be welcome, and yes, `unique=true` is not checked against the database, but an error like that would make you check the database schema again.